# What should I do to my goldfish swimming on surface?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, goldfish

I am new to goldfish, it is swimming on surface like gasping for air every 3 minutes or so. So, I did 40% water change, using drinking water just now. Should I do something else?

There is 24/7 filter and fan, though, I think it wasn't because of lack of oxygen, or is it? Should I buy bigger tank?

[image]

Comment: can you please edit the latest reading of your watertest into your question ammonia,nitrite,ph.what is the temperature of the water,is the tank properly cycled https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm

Comment: You wrote in your last question, that the siamese algae eater is lost in the tank, and that it was the only fish. Was it the only fish? If there was a goldfish with it, then this change the answers... And if your siamese is missing, do you let the goldfish in the same tank? Or is it a different one?

Comment: I dont have any test kit... but i have cycled it for 2 weeks, and i use api quick start , should i really buy that expensive test kit??

Comment: @allerleirauh yes, i search everywhere, i take off the tree, its gone... so later i bought goldfish and put it there....

Comment: It would be a one time -pay if you for example buy 50 test stripes for around 13 euros, then you could do 50 tests... testing helps a lot, because the most "toxic" things you could not see. The water would be clear, but your fish are at risk,,, especially if you have such small tanks, then little amounts of toxic substances will cause a big effect

Comment: Ok, ill buy it, and give update later

Comment: It takes 30 days to cycle a tank, your goldfish is suffering from ammonia poisoning.

Comment: In your other post you said that the tank volume is 10 gallons, goldfish need at least 20 gallons for a single goldfish and an additional 10 gallons for each goldfish beyond that, these fish are generally known for being dirty and generating a lot of waste, you and the fish will benefit from a bigger tank.

Comment: @Jestep Could you be convinced to convert that comment to an answer? Maybe even include lila's information. Just a short answer to this short question.

Comment: I don't see any air in that water or agitation on the surface (another sign that air is making it in).  Fish need air.  Usually, a filter (which I also don't see) will push enough air into the water but a bubbler never hurts.

Comment: @Elmy I think it's good idea, but also I assume we are still waiting for author to tell the results of testing water parameters.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell us whether there are any news about you aquarium, that would be helpful and interesting, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @lila, it was ammonia. But now i have goldfish in another bigger aquarium, it was tested ammonia safe. This aquarium is now home to betta fish also tested ammonia safe, its been 2 weeks, no dying or sick fish. Only algae needs to be cleaned. :v